# plugin cordova BluetoothLE

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugins

I've got some trouble using the BluetoothLE plug-in for apache cordova. This is the first time that I try to install one, so I may be missing something.

In my repo :
$cordova plugin ls
com.randdusing.bluetoothle 1.0.0 "Bluetooth LE"

So the plug-in should be installed.
And here is my js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //try to enable bluetooth
    bluetoothle.initialize(initializeSuccess, initializeError, true);
    $("#tiles").append($('Bye'));
});

function initializeSuccess(obj) {
    $("#tiles").append($('Hello'));
}

function initializeError(obj) {
    $("#tiles").append($('Hello'));
}
```

So, I should have on my application page an "Hello" followed by a "Bye", but it doesn't work. I haven't touch any file generated by cordova but www folder.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got it working.
Here's the full code :

index.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js :

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        alert("Hello");
        bluetoothle.initialize(initializeSuccess, initializeError, true);
        alert("Bye");
    }
};

function initializeSuccess(obj) {
    alert("Success");
}

function initializeError(obj) {
    alert("Failure");
}
```